# conflicting types for 'strtold'

Tags: c, centos

I run MUDs (coded in C) and have been migrating them to a new server. I run the same version of gcc on both (and same Makefile), but am getting errors on the new server when compiling:

```
/usr/bin/gcc34 -c -g -g3 -Wall    -DREQUESTS -DSMAUG14  -DTIMEFORMAT -DREGEX build.c
build.c:33: error: conflicting types for 'strtold'
/usr/include/stdlib.h:178: error: previous declaration of 'strtold' was here
```

The line:

```
long double     strtold         args( ( const char *string, const char **endstring) );
```

The stdlib.h line on the new server:

```
extern long double strtold (__const char *__restrict __nptr,
                        char **__restrict __endptr)
```

On stdlib.h in the same directory on the old server, same line:

```
extern long double strtold (__const char *__restrict __nptr,
                        char **__restrict __endptr)
```

But the old server does not receive this compile error. Old server gcc:

```
[user@old src]# /usr/bin/gcc34 -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,f77 --disable-libgcj --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-4.1)
```

New server gcc:

```
[user@new src]$ /usr/bin/gcc34 -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,f77 --disable-libgcj --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-19.el6)
```

Note that `args` is:

```
 #define args( list )                    ( )
```

What am I missing here? What could be pointing to a different library if the code, gcc version and Makefile are the same?

Update: Running `gcc -E` is starting to shed some light, old server:

```
3946.   extern long double __strtold_internal (__const char *__restrict __nptr,
3947.              char **__restrict __endptr,
3948.              int __group)
3949.        __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;
```

New server:

```
4525.   extern long double strtold (__const char *__restrict __nptr,
4526.          char **__restrict __endptr)
4527.        __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;
```

Clearly stdlib.h differs. Even though I have the same gcc versions, is there any way I can replicate the old library on the new server to ensure this migration is smooth?

I also notice this above the `strtold` extern in the library:

```
#ifdef  __USE_ISOC99
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_C99
```

Related? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21455370

Comment: Can you show us the complete definitions? And what is `args`? Presumably this is in case `strtold` does not exist. You should use a config program to determine which functions do and do not exist and build a header file based on that.

Comment: @Schwern Edited those in. The header and all code files are the exact same on both servers.

Comment: `strtold` is defined by the C standard library. Why is `build.c` redeclaring it?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm not the original developer of this MUD, I don't have this answer. I'm more the SysAdmin for many MUDs doing a migration. But MUDs are quite old as a note (1994 for this codebase).

Comment: @KeithThompson It's very common for software to define functions for portability purposes. Particularly older software that has to work with many compilers of questionable standards compliance. For example, [Perl has tons of this stuff](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/search?q=strtold&unscoped_q=strtold) though its pretty smart about it.

Comment: @KeithThompson It looks like the old server is using `__strtold_internal` from stdlib, causing this.

Answer (score 3):

Your signature does not match. Your definition has `const char *, const char **` but stdlib.h has `const char *, char **`. Note their second argument is not constant. Fix that and it might work.

Why it wasn't erroring before I can't say. You're using a 12 year old compiler on a 13 year old operating system.

Presumably this if for your own implementation of `strtold` in case it doesn't exist. Generally you want to run a config program which probes for the capabilities of the system and generates a header file with definitions like `#define HAS_STRTOLD`. Then you can wrap your compatibility versions with `#ifndef HAS_STRTOLD`.

It's possible your code does have something like this. On the old machine it found `strtold` and on the new one it does not. It's possible the probe is broken on the new machine.

Comment: I do understand why the error is occurring, but I'm trying to determine why these errors are appearing now. I am technically the host here and not the developer and I'm not sure I can take ownership of making code changes especially when there are dozens of MUDs hosted that may run into something like this.

Comment: @Zeno Tell them their code has a bug and they need to fix it. I added a possible reason why this might be happening.

Comment: I was planning on that, but these types of unknown scenarios will making migrating servers a huge pain as a MUD host. I don't see any HAS_STRTOLD anywhere for this MUD.

Comment: @Zeno It might not be called `HAS_STRTOLD`. We'd need to see the whole context of build.c to help further. Migrating old C code is likely to have issues, my condolences.

Comment: Updated question with gcc -E results showing some details on what is going on.